# Ubuntu stuck on language setting while installation

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, freeze, bios, system-settings

I am really struggling with the installation of my ubuntu. Screen freezes when I try to select language and click continue to install and provide further information.
Bio configuration:

- **Secure boot** - Disabled
- **UEFI mode**

And I also tried to another USB-thum but the issue remains
Please help I use Dell 7559 and Nvidia 960m ! Thanks

Comment: Still, have the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this!
When I access to grub menu to choose to install. I select the second option which is the installation then type "E" then add this line **nomodeset i915_bpo.nomodeset=1** just before the **quiet splash** then hit F10.

The computer will then start the installation process without any problem.
This is due to the incompatibility of the Nvidia and the technology provided by Ubuntu, so after the installation, when starting again the computer it will obviously freeze and this because the line of command that we provided before has disappeared, so the user should do the same when starting his computer hitting "E" typing the same thing and while accessing to Ubuntu he should make this parameter permanent by changing on the grub file:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line that reads **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""** to

If you are using Ubuntu 16.04

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=native acpi_osi="
```

If you are using 18.04 you may need to run this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi="
```

Finally run this command to apply the changes permanently

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: What if you have the stupid touch bar and no F10?  I can't seem to get Control-X to work either.

Comment: See this for workaround to "control-x doesn't work": https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux/issues/54

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.
  For other releases' hashes, like lubuntu, see:
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes
2) If using a CD/DVD, did you burn the disc as slowly as possible?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto
   If using USB install media, use a  tool like unetbootin or rufus. 
   Don't just copy files to the USB.
   See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick
3) Did you select the media check before trying to install?
   See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck
4) Did you ever do a "memory check" (perhaps another live-media menu choice) on your PC?
Doing the above can save you a lot of time struggling with a bad install media or
hardware problems.